# CakePHP 3 is NOT able to connect to the database due to a missing PHP extension

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am trying to install cakePHP 3.0.0 with WT-NMP, but i got this message:

> CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.
>
> Database driver Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql cannot be used due to a
>   missing PHP extension or unmet dependency

my php.ini has this:

```
extension = php_bz2.dll
extension = php_curl.dll
extension = php_gd2.dll
extension = php_imap.dll
extension = php_mbstring.dll
extension = php_exif.dll
extension = php_mysql.dll
extension = php_mysqli.dll
extension = php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension = php_pdo.dll
extension = php_soap.dll
extension = php_sockets.dll
extension = php_sqlite3.dll
extension = php_openssl.dll
extension = php_fileinfo.dll
extension = php_intl.dll
```

the app.php has this

```
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        /**
         * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
         * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
         * the following line and set the port accordingly
         */
        'port' => '3306',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'test',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
```

What am I missing? or this is cakePHP 3.0 bug? OR anything to do with WT-NMP.
I have been stuck for whole day.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solved this by luck!:

```
extension = php_intl.dll
extension = php_pdo_mysql.dll
intl.default_locale = en_utf8
intl.error_level = E_WARNING
```

Comment: Please explain with more steps.

Comment: More explanation would be better.

Comment: Specifically the extension = php_pdo_mysql.dll did it for me.

Answer (score 13):

Installing the [modules for MySQL database connections](https://packages.debian.org/sid/php5-mysql) solved it for me:

```
#Install the package
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
#Restart Apache
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Source: http://guru4cakephp.blogspot.nl/2015/04/install-cakephp-3-on-ubuntu.html

Package details: https://packages.debian.org/sid/php5-mysql

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

For PHP 7.0

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

For PHP 5:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Comment: Worked for me on php7.3 
sudo apt-get install php7.3-mysql

Answer (score 5):

The error message is because of `extension = php_pdo_mysql.dll` not being installed and enabled in `php.ini`. If you don't have `php_intl.dll` enabled you will get an error before checking the database connection.

Your `php.ini` indicates that you have got `php_pdo_mysql.dll` enabled, however it may have been that you needed to restart the [CakePHP server](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/quickstart.html#checking-our-installation) `bin/cake server`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't just depend on the php.ini reading. Just check if you have installed php[v]-mysql extension. You can check if php_mysql.dll exist in the php extension directory(most probably `<path to your php installation>/ext`) in your windows based server. In linux you can use the following command check if it is installed.

```
yum list installed | grep php
```

It will list down all the php extensions installed.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

```
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=sqlite3
```

Comment: Please add some kind of explanation addressing the thing you used in your answer or documentation mentioning the same.